# Vue.js updated hook for counting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, application-lifecycle, computed-properties

On the user's sidebar there is a number of new unseen notifications. This number is generated by a function which counts all new notifications with the flag `viewed: false` from API.

My question is: what will be good practice if I want to place this function in one of the lifecycle hooks inside the component of the sidebar? `updated()` or `computed`?

Comment: It should be `computed`. `computed` is good for derived values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `computed` if you - as it seems - want the component to change whenever the `computed` value changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!